# Suffix mutation on стрелок to стрелка

Tags: морфология, беглая-гласная

Here is the example where I found this word:

> Адвокаты назвали стрелка из Колорадо душевнобольным

Shouldn't it say стрелок?

Comment: to make it clear - you asking why it is not "стрелока"?

Comment: "стрелок" means "of arrows".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Стрелка́" is "стрело́к" ("shooter") in accusative.

In this sentence, "стрелка" is correct, because it is the object of "называть", which should have the accusative case:

> Адвокаты назвали стрелка из Колорадо душевнобольным.
>   Attorneys called the shooter from Colorado a madman.

Here is how word "стрелок" changes:

> **Nom**: стрелок
>   **Gen**: стрелка
>   **Acc**: стрелка
>   **Dat**: стрелку
>   **Ins**: стрелком
>   **Prp**: стрелке

The vowel "о" disappears in the suffix for historical reasons. This vowel stems from a reduced vowel "ъ" of the Old-Russian language. There were two reduced vowels in Old-Russian, "ъ" and "ь", and they disappeared in "weak" positions and changed into "о" and "e" in "strong" positions. One of the weak positions was the position before the stressed syllable, one of the strong positions was the position in the stressed syllable. This is exactly what we see in examples like "сынок":

> **Nom**: сънъкъ → сыно́к ("ъ" under stress becomes "o")
>   **Gen**: сънъкa → сынка́ ("ъ" before the stressed syllable disappears)

Now, as @Quassnoi says, this suffix appeared in the sense of profession much later, when the reduced vowels has already disappeared. But by that time it already existed in a two forms: "ок" in Nom Sg and "к" in other positions.

That is why there are disappearing vowels (called "fleeting vowels", thanks to @Quassnoi for terminology) in Russian words (and not only in suffixes, but also in stems, as "сон"–"сна" ("dream")).

Of course, there is no way you may know whether some "o" in some word stems from a full Old-Russian vowel "o" of from a reduced Old-Russian vowel "ъ", that's why you have to learn two word stems for nouns where the stress can be both on the stem and not on the stem.

Comment: +1 for explaining why in modern russia some vowels are reduced.

Comment: +1. This phenomenon is called fleeting vowel (*беглая гласная*)

Comment: On second thought: are you sure the form *стрѣлъкъ* was ever actually used? I believe this is just the loss of the palatalization in *стрѣлецъ* (which occured much later than the fall of the reduced) and the fleeting vowel is the result of contamination (like in *брелки < брелоки*). The other words with this suffix (*-ок* < *-ец*), like *игрок*, *ходок*, *ездок* etc. do not have a fleeting vowel.

Comment: @Quassnoi There were two different suffixes: -ък and ьк > -ец. Suffix -ък can be seen in modern "палка", "сынок", etc. I am not sure about "стрелок", though, I'll try to check whether this word existed at all in Old Russian.

Comment: Стрелец may be a borrowing from Church Slavonic.

Comment: @Olga: this suffix, even if borrowed, had been definitely once productive in Russian (and probably still is): *молодец*, *холодец* etc., note the Russian pleophony. My point is that *-ок* in this paradigm (professions and occupations) developed much later than the reduced have fallen and the fleeting vowel is not typical for it. The fleeting vowel in *стрелок* is the result of contamination with another *-ок* (diminutive) which, as you said, originates from **-ък*.

Comment: Ok, then it makes more sense. Thanks for your explanation! I'll change the example.

Comment: Now when I think of it, I realize that ък and ьк were positional variants, and the stem of стрелять actually ends with a palatalized consonant, so it actually had ьк, which changed into ец.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've mentions suffix mutation in the title, I guess you question is about
vowel missing.

The thing is in Russian the vowel suffix `-ек` and `-ок` is reduced in during declension. In words with `-ик` suffix the vowel remains.
Compare:

- мячик - мячика
- кролик - кролика

and

- стрелок - стрелка
- замок - замка

But! There are indeed cases when word with `-ок` endings is different.
Words like `игрок` do not lose `о` in the suffix, since this will cause a
quite untypical combination of consonants - `игрка` is inappropriate from the point of view of Russian phonology.

Also, one should not confuse `ок` as suffix and `ок` as part of the root ot the word. Examples: `порок`, `пророк`.

Comment: *курок* is an obvious calque from German *Hahn*, "hammer of a firearm" (compare English "to cock a gun"). *-ок* is clearly the suffix here and has a fleeting vowel.

Comment: @Quassnoi - курок is root in modern russian. There are cases in language evolution when suffix becomes part of the root, but as far as I remember, even this is not the case. But this is definitely typo, I've no intention to provide this example in a list with пророк and порок - this is a typo. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

No, in this sentence *стрелка* is an accusative case of the word *стрелок*.

Answer (score 0):

It would be `стрелок` in the following sentence:

```
Адвокаты назвали его так: "душевнобольной стрелок из Колорадо".
```